# react.js react-player does not show subtitle

Tags: reactjs, react-player

I am using the react-player component to play a movie with subtitle as it shows below:

```
import myVideo from '../media/test.mp4'

import React from 'react'
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player'

import './Video.css'

class Video  extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div className='player-wrapper'>
        <ReactPlayer
          url={myVideo}
          width='50%'
            height='50%'
            controls = {true}
            className='react-player fixed-center'
          config={{ file: {
            tracks: [
              {kind: 'subtitles', src: '../media/carol.vtt', srcLang: 'ro', default: true}
            ]
          }}}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Video
```

but the subtitle is not showed, even it is in the same folder with the movie

Best Regards,
Aurelian

Comment: I answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65945611/react-js-react-player-does-not-show-subtitle

Comment: I don t see your answer